# Function execution right based on external contract state, ballot and proposal example

Tags: contract-development, solidity

i'm building a sample application which require voting.
I think it needs to be split into 2 contracts where the owner of `Ballot` will create `Proposal` contracts. 
Splitting simply because the logic is got too complex to be clearly understandable in a single contract.

**Question:** what is the proper way to let only the `contributors` from `Ballot` contract vote for proposals.

My implementation - simply a call to `Bellot` to check if the address is in `contributors`. I've read that there are a lot of security flaws in interacting between 2 contracts(since i'm new to solidity might not know all details), so i want to verify if this is correct solution.

***Ballot***

```
contract Ballot {
    address public manager;
    mapping (address => bool) public contributors;

    Proposal[] proposals;
    mapping(address => Proposal[]) proposalsByAddress;

    constructor(address _creator) public {
        manager = _creator;
    }

    function createProposal() public {
        Proposal memory newProposal = new Proposal();
        proposalsByAddress[msg.sender].push(newProposal);

        //to be able to returl all porposals later
        proposals.push(newProposal);
    }

    function checkIfContributor(uint address _address) public view returns (bool) {
        require(proposalsByAddress[msg.sender]);

        if (contributors[_address]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

***Proposal:***

```
contract Proposal {
        Ballot ballot;
        bool complete;
        uint approveCount;
        uint rejectCount;
        mapping (address => bool) voters;

        constructor() {
            ballot = new Ballot(msg.sender);
        }

        function vote(bool _vote) {
            require(ballot.checkIfContributor(msg.sender));
            require(!voters[msg.sender]);

            voters[msg.sender] = true;
            if (_vote) {
                approveCount++;  
            } else {
                rejectCount++;
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some of it but I see circular logic.

You have a Ballot contract that creates new Proposals and when a new Proposal instantiates, it creates a new Ballot contract. So, what's going on?

As I understand it, there should be one Ballot contract and many Proposal contracts. The proposal contracts need an interface to the Ballot contract that deployed them.

Change,

```
ballot = new Ballot(msg.sender);
```

to

```
ballot = Ballot(msg.sender);
```

That will assign `ballet` to the `Ballot` contract at the address of `msg.sender`, which should be a `Ballot`.

As a matter of style, I would change this line:

```
if (contributors[_address]) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

to

```
return contributors[_address];
```

Since this is a read-only function I'd even consider passing in `address proposal` instead of relying on `msg.sender` so anyone can check anything.

Consider:

```
function isVoter(address proposal, address voter) public view returns(bool canIndeed) {
  require(proposalsByAddress[proposal]); // not a proposal (not ours), invalid request
  return contributors[voter]; // is a contributor overall
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! yeah it all sounds right. just forget that `new` will actually make a contract instead of initializing an interface. However, generally - is this the way this kind of relationship checks are done?

Comment: There is more than one way to approach it. Your hub and spoke approach is reasonable and you’re catching the important checks.